How to store PowerPoint Shape in OpenXML?
I have created a VSTO AddIn in C# - with a ribbon and a taskpane. My goal is, to store some manual created shapes in the POTX which I can read out from my AddIn and provide to be inserted in a slide.
I'm new with the openXML and customXMLPart - but already tried some stuff - e.g. to store some data in a customXMLPart and read it out later. I've read that the openXML File could contain not only tags, slides etc. but also Shapes.
So how could I insert in the POTX a custom shape which is then also available in a new created PPTX File - and accessable from the AddIn to be inserted into the slide?
Any ideas?
